# Start and stop times for non-invasive mechanical ventilation in MIMIC

Tags: mimic-iii

To obtain the start and stop times for non-invasive mechanical ventilation for each ICU stay event in MIMIC, I tried to use:

```
SELECT ICUSTAY_ID, MIN(CHARTTIME) start_mv, MAX(CHARTTIME) stop_mv
FROM mimiciii.CHARTEVENTS
WHERE ITEMID IN (225794)
GROUP BY ICUSTAY_ID;
```

since

```
SELECT itemid, label, linksto FROM mimiciii.d_items 
WHERE LOWER(label) LIKE '%vent%' ORDER BY itemid ASC;`
```

returns

[image]

However,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mimiciii.IOEVENTS WHERE ITEMID = 225794;
```

returns `0` so it doesn't work.

Which `ITEMIDs` should I look at to obtain the start and stop times for non-invasive mechanical ventilation in MIMIC?

E.g. for invasive mechanical ventilation, the `ITEMIDs` to look for are `('720', '722', '224685', '682', '683', '224686', '684', '224684', '721')`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also new to MIMIC and not an expert, but I recently discovered that it is possible to find start and stop times for mechanical ventilation in the `procedureevents_mv` table.